# I am using a basic script in Python but am getting the following error. What does it mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

```
arcpy.env.workspace("C:/Student/PythonGP10_0/Data/SanJuan.gdb")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
bufferList = []
for fc in fcList:
    if fc == "Lakes" or fc == "Streams":
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buffer", "1000 meters")
        bufferList.append(fc + "Buffer")
arcpy.Union_analysis(bufferList, "WaterBuffers")
```

Followed by this error when I run the script:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
 exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
 File "C:\Student\PythonGP10_0\Scripts\BufferWater.py", line 3, in <module>
 arcpy.env.workspace("C:/Student/PythonGP10_0/Data/SanJuan.gdb")
 TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Comment: It means somewhere you have a variable whose value is only a string (a unicode object) followed by parentheses, as if you're trying to call it like a function. That's all I can tell you without seeing any code at all.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: The code appears as follows:

Comment: import arcpy
#Set geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.workspace("C:/Student/PythonGP10_0/Data/SanJuan.gdb")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
#create list of features in SanJuan.gdb
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#create a loop to buffer Lakes and Streams
bufferList = []
for fc in fcList:
    if fc == "Lakes" or fc == "Streams":
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buffer", "1000 meters")
        bufferList.append(fc + "Buffer")
arcpy.Union_analysis(bufferList, "WaterBuffers")

Comment: Code should be edited into the question, not posted as a comment. Additionally, try to remove any portions that are irrelevant to the error.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000000w000000), `arcpy.env.workspace` should be set, not to be called:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Student/PythonGP10_0/Data/SanJuan.gdb"
```